# Запрос к MySQL c группировкой по двум параметрам

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Приветствую, можно ли сделать запрос к БД, который вернет сгруппированный результат по первому значению, где в каждой группе имеется сгруппированный результат по второму параметру? Или можно только сделать несколько запросов и потом объединить?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: ничего не понятно. почему в выходном массиве значения лесенкой. каждое значение в отдельной строке ? было бы логично просто вывести 4 строки, вроде 3:12:5, 3:13:4 и где тут какая то особая группировка. я вижу обычную группировку по 2 полям group_id и time

Comment: @Mike Сдается мне, что товарищ хочет не сагрегировать значения, а получит массив с двумя уровнями вложенности

Comment: Именно, хочется двумерный массив